# is there any way to pass the values betwn the htmls without using any other language

Tags: html

is there any way to pass and get the values betwn the htmls without using any other language like js, jsp, php and others , only html.

Answer (score 6):

simple answer NO

HTML is a markup language is only to create a view
nothing else

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only html the only thing you can do is display another page within your html using an iframe or frames. But I would not recommend those solutions. If you can get away with some javascript you can do way more with it. By you mentioning pass values it seems that you want to do some logic as the previous anwser stated HTML is only for the presentation layer.